# PyQt: Unequally divide the area occupied by widgets in a QHBoxLayout

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, pyqt

I want to have a layout like the following:

[image: Layout]

I am using a `QHBoxLayout` and adding two widgets - but instead of the 25% / 75% layout that I require, both the widgets get 50% of the available space.

How do I distribute the area for the widgets unequally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `QHBoxLayout` and `QVBoxLayout` classes allow you to set a *stretch factor* when [adding widgets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addWidget). This specifies the relative proportion of space taken up by the widget, *after* the widget's minimum/maximum width/height has been taken into account:

```
layout = QHBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(widget1, 25)
layout.addWidget(widget2, 75)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! @ekhumoro